# How to open full-featured android photo picker like google maps uses?

Tags: java, android, photo, mediastore

I'd like to use a photo picker like the one that google maps has, specifically one that combines recent photos, photo folders, and the option to capture a new photo from the camera. See example below.

[image: desired photo picker]

I don't need the multi-select or preview of selected photos option, just the part that starts with "yesterday".

My best guess is this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

but that opens a far less fancy picker that just shows the recent photos, without the "camera" button or the "folders" shortcut.

so is this interface built into android or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: Use Logcat and see what happens when you launch the photo picker from Maps. If that starts an activity, the basic details of the `Intent` action will be logged.

Comment: no intent is triggered. SO that means it's an internal fragment or activity? I would have thought an internal activity would still have posted an intent to logcat.

Comment: Try to remove the second parameter of the Intent constructor and create a chooser intent: Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(intent);

Comment: @Rediska: interesting idea. I just tried that and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not see a activity-start operation logged in Logcat, then you are seeing something internal to the Maps app: a fragment, a [composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), or something along those lines.

So, if you want that UI, you either need to write it yourself or see if there is [a third-party library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created) that offers something similar.